# How to make a redirect with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

All that i want to know is it possible to do with .htaccess some tricks (redirectings)

site.org/member/$var > site.org/member/?id=$var like this.

The point is just add the ?id (string constant) before $var.

It's gonna be something like

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (or RewriteMatch)... ...

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain

```
Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/
```

This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder

```
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
```

Redirect old file path to new file path

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Provide Specific Index Page (Set the default handler)

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

For details:  https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Or

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Details at: http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/member/(.*)$ $1/member/?id=$2 [L]
```

htaccess basics: http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !id=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^members/(.+)$ /member/?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```